# Copying attribute field into another layer and importing data from file into attribute table

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I am using QGIS 3.12 and wanna know how to copy and paste field attribute from one layer into another?

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Here is what I wanna do:

- copy all the attribute field from 1st pic to 2nd
- delete all field in 2nd pic which doesnt exist in 1st pic.
- and import the value from any file (e.g.: Excell, CSV format)

Comment: If those features share the same `"id"` you can achieve the result by means of `'Join by attribute'`.

Comment: I tried already but doesnt give the wanted result

Comment: Can you describe what you did more in details? Which geometry are you aiming to keep?